# When I run my TestCafe test script, my web application only displays the HTML form and not the JavaScript and CSS features. How can I fix this issue?

Tags: typescript, testcafe

When running my Test Cafe test script, I encounter an issue where the application only displays the HTML form and does not render the expected JavaScript and CSS features. This prevents me from properly testing the application's functionality. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

[here is the application view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJbuB.png)

My Test code is as below

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
```

```
fixtureCompare table data.pagehttps://example.com;
```

```
test('Compare table data between old and new application', async (t: TestController) => {
```

```
await t
    .typeText('#txt_login_database', 'Test_DB')
    .typeText('#txt_login_username', 'admin')
    .typeText('#txt_login_password', '123')
    .click('#btn_login_submit');

await t
    .click('#mega-menu-button')
    .click(Selector('a').withText('Settings'));
});
```

Comment: It's difficult to determine the cause of the issue based only on this information. Please create a simple sample that illustrates the issue.